# Explain These Services.xml File Terms In Shopware 6

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, shopware6, symfony-dependency-injection

What does `argument` and argument `type` mean,
What does `tag` and tag `name` mean,
in Shopware 6 plugin services.xml file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

```
<services>
    <service id="Winner\Service\ExampleService" />

    <service id="Winner\Service\ExampleServiceDecorator" decorates="Winner\Service\ExampleService">
        <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="product.loaded" />
        <argument type="service" id="Winner\Service\ExampleServiceDecorator.inner" />
    </service>
</services>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `services.xml` file is the configuration file for the [symfony dependency injection container](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html).

By default, Symfony allows autowiring of the config, but the Shopware default is to configure the DI container manually. Please refer to the [Symfony docs for more information on manually configuring the DI](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#explicitly-configuring-services-and-arguments).

And the [Symfony docs also have more information on service tags](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html).

So technically this is not a Shopware specific question, but rather a Symfony question. I hope my answer and the provided docs help you.